# why is this becoming from 'undefined' to 'object'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using next, chakra-ui and I don't know why this happens

src/pages/myAccount.tsx

```
import { Box, Link } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { withUrqlClient } from 'next-urql';
import React from 'react';
import { NavBar } from '../components/NavBar';
import { useGetUserByIdQuery } from '../generated/graphql';
import { createUrqlClient } from '../utils/createUrqlClient';

interface myAccountProps {}

const myAccount: React.FC<myAccountProps> = ({}) => {
const [{data, fetching},] = useGetUserByIdQuery();
console.log("1.", data);
if (!data) {
    return (
        <>
        Invalid Access, Not logged in
        </>
    )
}
console.log("2.", data);
let userInfo = data.getUserById;

return (
<>
<NavBar/>
    <Box>{userInfo.userId}</Box>
    <Box>{userInfo.userName}</Box>
    <Box>{userInfo.univ}</Box>
    <Box>{userInfo.sex}</Box>
    <Box>{userInfo.firstName}</Box>
    <Box>{userInfo.lastName}</Box>
    <Box>{userInfo.age}</Box>
    <Box>{userInfo.email}</Box>
</>);
}

export default withUrqlClient(createUrqlClient)(myAccount);
```

when I executed this code, it doesn't work at all.
And I got console log like this

```
1. undefined
1. {getUserById: null}
2. {getUserById: null}
1. {getUserById: null}
2. {getUserById: null}
```

My question is, just after "if", why is data becoming from "undefined" to "object"?

Comment: Because `useGetUserByIdQuery` returns it like that?

Comment: "just after "if", why is data becoming from "undefined" to "object"?" --- it does not become like that after `if`, it becomes like that next render loop. See that you have two `1.`

Comment: When the data is fetched, your `useGetUserByIdQuery` hook is likely setting the `data` state inside of it.  When data is set with new values in your hook, your component receives the new value from the hook and rerenders itself with data as an `object` instead of `undefined`.

Comment: As @ChanYoun noticed, you're likely getting data from the hook which is doing some async work causing that to change and the component to re-render.  You might be able to leverage `fetching` so that `if (fetching) { return null }` before you start looking at the `data` portion.  At that point, your `data` should have been resolved as an object (if we are properly guessing at what the `useGetUserByIDQuery` is doing).